# Google Maps API: How to display hidden Marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I followed the official API docs and came up with a function like so:

```
function setMapOnAll(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
    }
```

However, I am trying to write a function that can *"unhide"* some of the markers, but I can't find any documentation on undoing this action. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your most likely problem is that the value of `map` in the global scope (or at least the scope in which you are executing `setMapOnAll`) is null, rather than a reference to the map on which you want to display the markers.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just call `setMap()` on the markers you want to show and pass it an instance of `google.maps.Map` rather than `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The map variable needs to be in the global scope (HTML click listener functions run in the global scope).

[proof of concept fiddle with global map variable](http://jsfiddle.net/9ctztzps/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// global variables
var map;
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
  // initialize global map variable
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter()
  });
  markers.push(marker1);
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {
      lat: 37.4529598,
      lng: -122.1817252
    }
  })
  markers.push(marker2);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="setMapOnAll(null);" value="hide" />
<input type="button" onclick="setMapOnAll(map);" value="show" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```